# Eclipse: Android project API level

Tags: android, eclipse

I've imported an Android project into Eclipse which generates errors like:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The type java.lang.Class cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The type android.app.Instrumentation cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
 files
- The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

The solution is to install Android API Level 18. However, my question is - where is this specified in the project?

If I look at `project.properties` I see:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-18
```

which clearly states API level 18. However, I don't see where this comes from. E.g. looking in Project Properties I don't see a Project Build Target specified:

[image: Project Properties]

and in the Manifest file it says `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />` so I'd assume it would have used `API Level 17`. But it doesn't. It seems to require `API Level 18`.

So, where is this specified?

Comment: It is specified in the Project Properties Android/Project Build Target, but since you don't have it installed it can't be showed.

Comment: So surely it's specified in some text file somewhere in the project?

Comment: Is in the project.properties as you said, and  the manifest also have `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` , the minSdkVersion means that the projecto could be runned in that version, but it can only be compile in the targetSdk.

Comment: So seeing as I've got the Android 4.2.2 SDK (i.e. API Level 17) why doesn't it compile with just that available?

Comment: I think that they use the API level to determine wich instance of the Java virtual machine use to compile the code you're writting, if you want to compile the project without downloading just change the number in the project.properties. Also the documentation says that the min and max Sdk is for the device to be able to run it, not to compile it, and the target sdk is the level on wich the app is designed to run. See the part of [Selecting version an API Level](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#fc) of the official developer guide.